# Conversion of VSTO 4.0 Excel Addin from VS2013 Ultimate on Window 7 to VS2013 Professional on Windows 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, vsto, office-addins, officedev

I have developed an Excel Add-In using Visual Studio Tools for Office (v4.0) in VS2013 Ultimate Edition on Window 7 platform. 
Now i have to convert my Excel Add-In to VS2013 Professional Version on Windows 10 due to some licensing issues.

Let it me if someone has gone through similar work. 
what possible issues can i expect during the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

None. VSTO 4 is no different between the Ultimate and Professional edition of Visual Studio 2013. In fact it doesn't depend on Visual Studio in the first place, just the development tools do, and they are the same on both version too. So there is no conversion necessary at all.

Developing on Windows 10 instead of Windows 7 will have no major difference too.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wanted to mark it as answer but then i thought it would be better to update it after testing the scenarios on my site first. iwill mark it as Answer after  that.

Comment: No problem. Take your time.

Comment: As a site note. I have just done the same here locally, and it just works.

Answer (score 1):

> Let it me if someone has gone through similar work. what possible issues can i expect during the conversion?

Nothing. It doesn't matter what edition of Visual Studio or OS you use.

The same libraries VSTO are included in all paid editions of VS.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help.